# How to integrate Spring log4j with messages.properties?

Tags: spring-boot

I want to implement a method that outputs a log based on the value of message.proerpties using the following interface. What should I do?
`logger#info(String messagePropertyKey, Object[] placeholderValues)`

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your file is message.properties:

```
messages.success= the service {} is called successfully. 
messages.error= the service {} failed with reason {}.
```

```java
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties
@PropertySource("classpath:message.properties")
public class LogMessagesHolder {

    private Map<String, String> messages;
    
    public String getMessage(final String key){
    return messages.get(key);
    }


}
```

Now, you can use the `LogMessagesHolder` by autowiring it where you want

```java
@Slf4J
@Component
public class LogMessagesHolderTest {

    @Autowired
    private LogMessagesHolder logMessagesHolder

    public void testLogSuccess() {
        logger.info(logMessagesHolder.getMessage("success"), serviceA);
    }

    public void testLogError() {
        logger.error(logMessagesHolder.getMessage("error"), "serviceA", "failureReason");
    }
}
```